# How to print a set of for-looped arrays in a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This was my original code to print out the information entered into the program, it was designed to create a nice little table displaying tutor names on the left with their pay on the right, and the total pay of all at the bottom:

```
System.out.println("Tutor Stipend Report");
System.out.println("Tutors\t\tPay");
System.out.println("------\t\t---");
for(int out=0;out<numOfTutors;out++) {
    System.out.println(names[out]+"\t\t"+stipend[out]);
}
System.out.println("--------");
System.out.println("Total: " +sum);
```

Now I need to turn this code to display in `JOptionPane` and here is where I am stuck.  I want to keep the same table setup as before but every time I go to display the information, lets say I need to display 3 tutors, it will just come up with 3 `JOptionPane` dialog boxes instead of printing the 3 tutors in one dialog box.

I realize the problem is because all the information is inside the for loop, but how do I resolve this issue so I can display the designated number of tutors and pay on one dialog box like I had with the `System.out.println` solution?

```
for (int out=0;out<numOfTutors;out++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                                "Tutor Stipend Report" + 
                              "\nTutors        Pay" + 
                              "\n---------         -----" + 
                              "\n"+names[out]+"               "+stipend[out] + 
                              "\n--------" + 
                              "\nTotal: " +sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` outside of the `for`-loop.

Check out [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).  It's helpful for this sort of thing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("There are ").append(count).append(" people in the following list:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append("Person #").append(count).append('\n');
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

Comment: +1 The solution is fine, just as side note, you can also wrap the text in `<html>` tags and use HTML formatting (such as `<table>`) to produce better formatted results - JFYI

Comment: This solution worked perfect, thank you so much, I had never heard of StringBuilder but it was a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is since you're calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` inside the loop, it will execute 3 times. What you should do instead is concatenating the string you want to print into one string object like this:

```
String toBeDisplayed = "";
for(int out=0;out<numOfTutors;out++) {
   toBeDisplayed += /*.. add your string here.. */;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, toBeDisplayed);
```

Note that cocatenating string using += is not the most efficient thing to do -- consider using StringBuilder / StringBuffer

Comment: Thank you for your response, I ended up going with StringBuilder from what the previous user had told me, thank you again though.